# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Item not found Concurrent read/write on ORC table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, google-cloud-storage

When I try concurrent read/write on a table using spark application, I get the following error:

```
19/10/28 15:26:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 213.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 407, prod.internal, executor 3): java.io.FileNotFoundException: Item not found: 'gs://bucket/db_name/table_name/p1=xxx/part-1009-54ad3fbb-5eed-43ba-a7da-fb875382897c.c000'. If you enabled STRICT generation consistency, it is possible that the live version is still available but the intended generation is deleted.
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageExceptions.getFileNotFoundException(GoogleCloudStorageExceptions.java:38)
at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.open(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:631)
```

I am using Google Cloud Dataproc Version 1.4 and stock hadoop component versions.
I was previously writing and reading from same partition of a PARQUET table but it used to throw a refresh table error. Now I'm using an `ORC` format table, but the error stays somewhat same. Any solutions for concurrent read/write on hive tables using spark applications?

Comment: Is this exception occurring while performing a read operation and is there a concurrent write operation ?

Comment: @jjayadeep Yes, there is concurrent read/write operation going on same partition.

Answer (score 2):

You can try running;

```
spark.sql("refresh table your_table")
```

statement before your read/write operation it can work "occasionally".

Answer (score 0):

First error line indicates that you were file was not found in your bucket, you may want to look into this. Make sure to check the existence of your folders and make sure the files and the requested versions  are accessible.

For the “STRICT generation consistency”, this is most probably related to Cloud Storage and produced by the connector, more precisely related to “Strongly consistent operation’.
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/consistency

Have you looked into your error logs to see why this error occurs? What type of environment are you running your application on?

This may be more of a Hive issue relating to the concurrency mechanism in which you want to implement.
 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Locking

Also, I would advise you to look more into the recommendations and functionalities of using Apache Hive on Cloud Dataproc. You can also consider using a multi-regional bucket if the Hive data needs to be accessed from Hive servers that are located in multiple locations.
https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-apache-hive-on-cloud-dataproc

Comment: 1. I am using LATEST for generation consistency.
2. Concurrency is off.
3. I am using all recommended settings.
I am using google cloud dataproc. One more thing I noticed is that when I switch the table location to hdfs instead of google storage, then there is no issue.